# Why is my hashrate so low? (R9 280x at 7 mhs / GTX 960 Strix at 2 mhs)

Tags: mining, hashrate

I have two graphics card (1x R9 280x and 1x GTX 960 STRIX 4 GB version). By using the Claymore Miner I only get 7.5 Mh/s with the r9 and 2.5 Mh/s with the GTX...

I'm using Win10, 16 GB RAM, Z170 Pro Gaming Mainboard, 500 W Power supply and an Intel i7 6700

All drivers are installed.

What is the problem? What am I doing wrong? How can I improve my hashrate?

Thank you so much! Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: that gpu is old use Polaris or pascal only

Comment: I couldn't say what the problem is from that information, but can say your 500W power supply had better be a good quality unit; you're cutting it a bit close, even excluding effects like capacitor aging, especially if using a supply from one of the less-scrupulous companies that is, shall we say, optimistic about the load sustainable by their products. If you really want an answer about your hash rate, I'd say the first thing to check is your R9 280x drivers. I believe Claymore suggests a 15.x series drivers, not the new Crimson drivers. The 960 is probably put to better uses. Like gaming.